# Is this grammatical "one of them say~"?

Tags: grammar

I was listening to BBC while reading the script and the announcer said...

"Then I heard **one** of them **say** his parents were dinosaurs"

Is that correct?  I don't think so.

Comment: You think wrong. BBC are perfectly correct.

Comment: this question already has an answer ?  No, it has never been asked before. I asked about word choice. "one say" does not make sense.   not about something like " I heard him leaving "

Answer (score 0):

"Say" in this sentence is an infinitive.